# When a function behave when "return" out o of the function in C++

Tags: c++

I have a code. like this:

```
int functionA (){
    Foo(**,**,**);
    return 0;
}
```

Foo() is a huge function(more than 10,000 lines). Which I don't understand all.Foo function includes some multi-thread code.

The problem now is, if I have "return" code right after Foo, Foo can be run correctly.

If I insert some other code (even a really simple cout code) between Foo() and "return". The Foo function will act weird(partly not run correctly).

I debugged this thing for 3 days. Nothing found.

Comment: You say the code is multithreaded. cout has some cancellation points which if not used with lockes properly might cause multithreaded caode to behave abnormally

Comment: My first guess is that it is an accident that foo( ) runs correctly. Somewhere in foo( ) some code is screwing up the stack somehow. So you have to keep looking in that function to find the problem. That would be my approach.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440576/simple-detached-pthread-does-not-cancel-cout-blocks-and-interleaves-even-if-mut . this might be of some help

Comment: I don't subscribe at all to the theory that if it can't fit one one screen, the function is too big.  But, damn.  10k lines for one function?  really?  What kind of jacked up mess is that?!

Comment: why people de-vote my post.? happy?

Comment: Anders, I did not d/v your post, but I would surmise that others did because it was low-quality.  If you had read the FAQ you'd have learned that questions on SO are expected to be "practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."  This question is neither practical nor answerable.  We know nothing about Foo, and you never actually asked a question.  If you reformulate your question to include a *small* (10 lines or so) code sample that we can compile & run which will replicate your problem, tell us the bahavior you see and what you expected to see, you'll be happier.

Comment: Link to FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known as a race condition, some of your code is likely interfering with the operation of Foo(), without a more detailed description of the problem it is impossible to determine how to fix it.  Either sleep() while the threaded operations are in progress, or read the documentation to determine if foo() can be safely operated on, and if a flag is set by foo to indicate when it is thread safe.